# Difference between function(e) and function()

Tags: jquery

What is the significant/difference between the following code? (e) at the end

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.something', function(e) {

vs.

jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.something', function() {
```

Thanks!

Comment: The first one passes the `event` object to the anonymous function, whereas the second one doesn't. Try logging the variable. See: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: Technical details: The event object is *always* passed to the 'on' callback function as the first *argument* (per the documentation), but only the function with a *parameter* can access the supplied argument by the `e` name - if accessing such is not required then the parameter can be safely omitted and it will not affect the program. In both cases the supplied argument(s) can be accessed via `arguments`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `e` parameter is the event triggered, which is the [jQuery `event` object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). Both the cases, [`event`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) is created, but to access it, we are passing it as parameter.

```
// Case 1
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.something', function(e) {
  e.which;     // Short form. This is Click Event object.
});

// Case 2
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.something', function() {
  // There's no reference to the event that's triggered.
});
```

Comment: `window.event` is a microsoft-specific implementation and not standard.

Comment: The `window.event` object only exists for IE. It's not correct still.

Comment: `event` is *not* the same object as the one jQuery passes to the callback.

Comment: @Juhana I have given the reference to the jQuery event object only. Check please.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Your second example would throw `ReferenceError: event is not defined` in FF.

Comment: Now *"Both the cases, event is triggered. But the way we take it differs."* doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 6):

There is technically no difference in the 2 expressions. `'e'` refers to the event variable which is optional and works more like `this` expression in `jquery`. you can use that `e` variable to figure out certain information like the target which invoked the event or any other property.

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.something', function() {
  alert(this.id); // gives you the id of the element using this
}); 

jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.something', function(e) {
   alert(e.target.id); // gives you the id of the element using event
});
```

In my opinion, the biggest advantage of using the event `e` is that it gives you more correct info compared to `this` when the event handlers are invoked over the `document`.

```
$(document).on('click',function()
{
  alert($(this).attr("id")); // id as undefined
})

$(document).on('click',function(e)
{
  alert(e.target.id); // gets the correct id
})
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/twjwuq92/